# R :How to execute FOR loop for Kmeans

Tags: r

I have an input file with Format as below :

```
RN KEY  MET1    MET2    MET3    MET4
1   1   0.11    0.41    0.91    0.17
2   1   0.94    0.02    0.17    0.84
3   1   0.56    0.64    0.46    0.7
4   1   0.57    0.23    0.81    0.09
5   2   0.82    0.67    0.39    0.63
6   2   0.99    0.90    0.34    0.84
7   2   0.83    0.01    0.70    0.29
```

I have to execute Kmeans in R -separately for DF with Key=1 and Key=2 and so on...
Afterwards the final output CSV should look like

```
RN  KEY MET1    MET2    MET3    MET4    CLST
1   1   0.11    0.41    0.91    0.17    1
2   1   0.94    0.02    0.17    0.84    1
3   1   0.56    0.64    0.46    0.77    2
4   1   0.57    0.23    0.81    0.09    2
5   2   0.82    0.67    0.39    0.63    1
6   2   0.99    0.90    0.34    0.84    2
7   2   0.83    0.01    0.70    0.29    2
```

Ie Key=1 is to be treated as separate DF and Key=2 is be treated as separate DF and so on...
Finally the output of clustering (of each DF)is to be combined with Key column first (since Key cannot participate in clustering) and then combined with each different DF for final output

```
In the above example :
DF1 is 
KEY MET1    MET2    MET3    MET4
1   0.11    0.41    0.91    0.17
1   0.94    0.02    0.17    0.84
1   0.56    0.64    0.46    0.77
1   0.57    0.23    0.81    0.09

DF2 is 
KEY MET1    MET2    MET3    MET4
2   0.82    0.67    0.39    0.63
2   0.99    0.90    0.34    0.84
2   0.83    0.01    0.70    0.29
```

Please suggest how to achieve in R

```
Psuedo code :
n<-Length(unique(Mydf$key))
   for i=1 to n
       {
          #fetch partial df for each value of Key and run K means
             dummydf<-subset(mydf,mydf$key=i
            KmeansIns<-Kmeans(dummydf,2)
          # combine with cluster result
              dummydf<-data.frame(dummydf,KmeansIns$cluster)

      # combine each smalldf into final Global DF
       finaldf<-data.frame(finaldf,dummydf)
        }Next i

  #Now we have finaldf then it can be written to file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using data.tables.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,CLST:=kmeans(.SD, centers=2)$clust, by=KEY, .SDcols=3:6]
DF
#    RN KEY MET1 MET2 MET3 MET4 CLST
# 1:  1   1 0.11 0.41 0.91 0.17    2
# 2:  2   1 0.94 0.02 0.17 0.84    1
# 3:  3   1 0.56 0.64 0.46 0.70    1
# 4:  4   1 0.57 0.23 0.81 0.09    2
# 5:  5   2 0.82 0.67 0.39 0.63    2
# 6:  6   2 0.99 0.90 0.34 0.84    2
# 7:  7   2 0.83 0.01 0.70 0.29    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to use `by`. Something along the lines of

```
by(data = DF, INDICES = DF$KEY, FUN = function(x) {
  # your clustering code here
})
```

where `x` is a subset of your `DF` for each `KEY`.

Comment: Could you suggest a solution using For loop in R please

Comment: As i need to feed x every time in to this command,i am beginner in R and hence need help

Answer (score 0):

```
#Read data
mdf <- read.table("mydat.txt", header=T)

#Convert to list based on KEY column
mls <- split(mdf, f=mdf$KEY)

#Define columns to use in clustering
myv <- paste0("MET", 1:4)

#Cluster each df item in list : modify kmeans() args as appropriate
kls <- lapply(X=mls, FUN=function(x){x$clust <- kmeans(x[, myv],
    centers=2)$cluster ; return(x)})

#Make final "global" df
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, kls)
```

Comment: I have already read the data into a data frame hence need a solution to traverse in df only

Comment: If all solutions suggested for this problem seem rather unfamiliar to you, I would kindly recommend that you instead spend some time reading up on the basics of the R language i.e. before getting into K-means and all. Just google "Introduction to R": plenty of resources out there.cheers.